# How Qt handle a QList<QList<QByteArray> > in Q_PROPERTY?

Tags: qt, properties, wizard

In my class, I want a member with type  `QList<QList<QByteArray> >` as a property, should the `Q_PROPERTY` call be:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QList myData READ myData)
```

or

```
typedef QList<QList<QByteArray> > TYPE_LLB;
Q_PROPERTY(TYPE_LLB myData READ myData)
```

?

Actually I'm trying `QWizard` and `QWizardPage`classes, data with type`QList<QList<QByteArray> >` need to be propagated among pages, Qt manual says `registerField` and `field` methods help, but these two methods need widget properties to be defined correctly.

Please help. Thanks!